# Build ffmpeg for windows phone 8

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

How could I build ffmpeg for windows phone 8, arm?. I couldn't find any info about it.

Could I call from c++ to h.264 hardware encoder/decoder in windows phone 8? It looks like Media Foundation is too limitted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it is not possible to compile ffmpeg for Windows Phone 8 at the moment due to a missing toolchain. But there is a kickstarter project for a Windows 8 port (http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1061646928/vlc-for-the-new-windows-8-user-experience-metro), stating that there will be a version for ARM tablets as well. Once they release the project with a possible toolchain it is very likely that the project can be compiled for Windows Phone 8 as well (probably with some modifications).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout MoliPlayer for Windows Phone 8. It should be using FFMPEG as decoder library to support various video/audio codecs. (Is there anything else?)

So I guess that FFMPEG can be compiled for WP8. However, MoLi team probably won't going to share their custom build GCC toolchain.