# ffmpeg compilation issue on Windows phone 8.1

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Taking a look at [Build ffmpeg for windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789252/build-ffmpeg-for-windows-phone-8)
I was able to compile ffmpeg on Windows phone 8using these steps:

**My configuration**

OS: Windows 8.1 VS: Ultimate 2013 Update 3 (If armasm fails, msvcdis110.dll missing download it from dllsearch ) Mingw (be sure that "link" and "cl" commands point to MS "link" and "cl") FFmpeg 2.1.5

Follow prerequisites listed here: https://ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b-or-Intel-C_002b_002b-Compiler-for-Windows

-) Download c99toc89: https://github.com/libav/c99-to-c89/downloads/. Be sure all files from c99toc89 are in Mingw PATH (copy in /bin)

-) FFMPEG requires stdint.h and inttypes.h headers standardized as a part of C99. Unfortunately, Visual Studio does not include these files. Fortunately, there is a project that fixes this issue. Download the latest version and unpack it to Visual Studio includes (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include).

-) Launch cmd and "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86_arm" and then msys

-) configure:

```
./configure --toolchain=msvc \
--disable-programs \
--disable-network \
--disable-protocols \
--extra-cflags="-D_ARM_WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP_SDK_AVAILABLE -D_M_ARM -D_WINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPIFAMILY_APP" \
--enable-cross-compile \
--target-os=win32 \
--arch=arm \
--as=armasm \
--cpu=armv7 \
--disable-yasm \
--extra-ldflags="-MACHINE:ARM" \
--disable-dxva2 \
--disable-asm \
--disable-doc
```

I was able to get .a static libs but I wasn't able to generate an app using it. I have problems while linking for kernel32.lib and libcmt.lib misses.

Anyone?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am wondering if vcvarsall x86_arm replaces the vcvarsphoneall I used to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting error *.lib missing error you can run export command like libcmt.lib is in below path in my system

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/lib"
```

this worked for me.